# Delete event for custom stamps in pdftron

Tags: pdf, confirmation, pdftron, stamp

I want to add a confirmation dialog box when user clicks on the delete icon for deleting a custom stamp but the stamp disappears from dropdown list as soon as the click the button. It show up when you open the file again or we load it up again but its not good user experience. Is there any deletion event pdftron provides so that I can implement all the logic at our end from there?

[Here is the screenshot of the delete button I am referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYcrK.png)

I tried finding the event but couldn't find one. I tried loading the stamp again as it wasn't deleted from our end but it causes a glitch (disappears and reappears) and its not a good user experience.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the new ['customStampsDeleted' event](https://docs.apryse.com/api/web/Core.Tools.RubberStampCreateTool.html#event:customStampsDeleted__anchor) which is available in the latest WebViewer version.

Comment: I don't have the latest version yet. I'll look into it. Thanks.